# mapping list to the binary data

Tags: python, pandas

let us suppose that in my dataframe,  we have following categorical  data [3,4,5,6,7,8,9], i want to  map values [3,4,5,6,7] to the zero and [8,9]  to the one, of course i can use np.where function, but  i have tried dictionary method like this

```
winequality["quality"] =winequality["quality"].map({[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:0,[8, 9]:1})
```

where winequality is dataframe and quality is column, what i have got is  this error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

i have tried such kind of mapping and it was working fine, so exactly i dont remember  which part i am missing, could you  help me please?

Comment: Keys of dictionary can not be of type `list`. `dict` keys must be `immutable`.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma s/immutable/hashable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to `map()` it, the `dict` keys need to be enumerated, not as a list, e.g.:

```py
zeros = {key: 0 for key in [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
ones = {key: 1 for key in [8, 9]}
winequality["quality"] = winequality["quality"].map({**zeros, **ones})
```

Comment: in short can  list be converted  to the  acceptable format? for instance set or like this?

Comment: Not in a way that can be used for `map()`. The keys could be `tuple` or something, but then pandas won't map the tuple elements as desired.

Comment: In this case then simple  way is use np.where right

Comment: Yes I believe `np.where` is best here

Comment: And is also generally faster than `map`

Answer (score 4):

#### Setup

```
>>> winequality

   quality
0        3
1        4
2        5
3        6
4        7
5        7
6        8
7        9
8        9
9        8
```

### 1. `Series.map`

Instead of `list` we can create a dictionary with `tuple` as its keys, then flatten the dictionary, and `map` the values

```
dct = {(3, 4, 5, 6, 7):0, (8, 9): 1}
dct = {i:v for k, v in dct.items() for i in k}

winequality['quality'].map(dct)
```

#### 2. `Series.replace`

`replace` can be used without requiring to `flatten` the dictionary first.

```
dct = {(3, 4, 5, 6, 7):0, (8, 9): 1}
winequality['quality'].replace(dct)
```

#### Result

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
Name: quality, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realize this `replace()` behavior, TIL +1

Comment: Yes `replace` is sometimes very `handy` to use ;).

Comment: aaa, i think that i have used replace exactly and  remembered somehow  map, thanks for advice

Answer (score 2):

I believe the part where you try to create the dictionary is wrong: `{[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]:0,[8, 9]:1}`. You should replace this with

```
d1 = {k: 0 for k in [3,4,5,6,7]}
d2 = {k: 1 for k in [8,9]}
d = {**d1, **d2}
```

That would give you

```
{1: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 9: 1, 10: 1}
```

for `d`, which you can then use in `.map`.